# Make divs overlap when space is not enough

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a container with fixed sized boxes inside.

- The container does not have a fixed width. It fills the entire screen width.
- The boxes have to be always aligned to the right.
- The boxes should have a margin between them.

[image]

When the container resizes (browser window becomes small), currently the boxes will break into a second line.

[image]

But this is not what I want.

What I want is the boxes to remain in the **same line** and **reduce the margin between the boxes** to make space to keep them  in the same line.
When there is no space at all, I want the boxes to overlap each other to keep themselves in the same line.

[image]

How do I make the boxes stay in the same line and overlap each other when there is no space, and spread out nicely like in the first image when there is enough space?

Comment: Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xuyypxjj/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I came up with. If I calculated it mathematically it would have probably taken less time and would have been more accurate. Don't mind the jQuery, it's just toggling class `.small` on and off on the element so you can see it at different sizes, through the animation. You can just remove it and change the size manually, from inspector:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  padding-right: 0;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container .box {
  margin: 0 calc(((75% / 25) - 12px) + 5%);
  min-width: 25px;
}
.container .box:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```js
function toggleSmallClass(el) {
  el.toggleClass('small');
  setTimeout(function(){toggleSmallClass(el)}, 1200)
}
toggleSmallClass($('.small'))
```

```css
.container {
  border: 2px dotted orange;
  text-align: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container.large {
  width: 250px;
}

.box {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2%;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
}

.a {
  background-color: Tomato;
}

.b {
  background-color: Orange;
}

.c {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.d {
  background-color: MediumSeaGreen;
}

.container.small {
  width: 50px;
}
.container {
  transition: width 1.2s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
}

.container {
  width: 250px;
  display: flex;
  padding-right: 0;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container .box {
  margin: 0 calc(((75% / 25) - 12px) + 5%);
  min-width: 25px;
}
.container .box:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container large">
  <div class="box a">
    A
  </div>
  <div class="box b">
    B
  </div>
  <div class="box c">
    C
  </div>
  <div class="box d">
    D
  </div>
</div>
<br />
Small Container
<div class="container small">
  <div class="box a">
    A
  </div>
  <div class="box b">
    B
  </div>
  <div class="box c">
    C
  </div>
  <div class="box d">
    D
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot! This is great. Can you explain how this works `0 calc(((75% / 25) - 12px) + 5%)`

Comment: sets `top` and `bottom` margins to `0` and `left` and `right` to that `calc()`, where `100%` is the width of the parent. it ranges from negative margins when parent width is below `100px` to positive ones as the parent width grows. When toying with it I realized I was doing it wrong. This would have been a lot simpler if I used pseudo elements for the colored squares, positioned absolute and centered on each child. Than childs wouldn't have to have fixed width and could overlap easier. If I had to do it again I'd do it with pseudos.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is like a trick, but it works exactly as you want.

```css
.container {
  border: 2px dotted orange;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 105px;
}

.wrap:last-child {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 100px;
}

.wrap div {
  align-items: center;
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 100px;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100px;
}

.wrap:nth-child(1) div {
  background: green;
}

.wrap:nth-child(2) div {
  background: blue;
}

.wrap:nth-child(3) div {
  background: red;
}

.wrap:nth-child(4) div {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div>A</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div>B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div>C</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div>D</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use flexbox for this.

Created a fiddle for you.

Would something like this solve your problem?

https://jsfiddle.net/pcehxx7f/8/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">A</div>
  <div class="box">B</div>
  <div class="box">C</div>
  <div class="box">D</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  display: flex;  
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.box {
  background: #CCC;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this...

```
.container.small {
  width: 60px;
  height: 25px;
}
.box-small {
  width: 20px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-right: -8px !important;
}
```

Here's [Changed fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xuyypxjj/2/)

Answer (score 0):

use JS to get that i have added jQuery:

did a bit change in your `css` setted the margin to 2px rather than 2%, added jquery and some JS code. Works perfectly...you can copy my code and check it out...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var b=$(".small").width();
    console.log(b);
  if(b<120){
    var auto="-"+(120-b)/4 + "px";
     $(".small").children().css("margin-right",auto);
 
  }
  var ma=2;
  $(window).resize(function(){
     b=$(".small").width();
      if(b<120){
    var auto="-"+(120-b)/4 + "px";
     $(".small").children().css("margin-right",auto);
 
  }
     var a= $(window).width();

  if(a<150){
    --ma;
    var margin=ma+"px";
    $(".large").children().css("margin-right",margin);
    $(".small").children().css("margin-right",margin);
  }
    else{
          $(".large").children().css("margin-right","2px");
          ma=2;
    }

  })
})
```

```css
.container {
  border: 2px dotted orange;
  text-align: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container.large {
  max-width: 120px;
}

.box {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2px;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
}

.a {
  background-color: Tomato;
}

.b {
  background-color: Orange;
}

.c {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.d {
  background-color: MediumSeaGreen;
}

.container.small {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
<div class="container large">
  <div class="box a">
    A
  </div>
  <div class="box b">
    B
  </div>
  <div class="box c">
    C
  </div>
  <div class="box d">
    D
  </div>
</div>
<br />
Small Container
<div class="container small">
  <div class="box a">
    A
  </div>
  <div class="box b">
    B
  </div>
  <div class="box c">
    C
  </div>
  <div class="box d">
    D
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: forgot  to delete console.log

Answer (score 0):

You can add `float: left` and set `margin:0` in new class,
here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dedi_wibisono17/xuyypxjj/3/)