# responsive overlapping elements when there is not enough space

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, flexbox

here is my scenarios...

- elements (divs, li) start overlapping each other like a stacked card pack when there is not enough space. (on window resize)
- but when there is enough space and even more i want them to be next each other with 5px margin max (not any extra margins between them).
- elements are fixed width and height.
- elements can be more than 5 and less, even 1.

i tried absolute position and calc() but didn't work.
should i need to do js jquery or it can done with css?

what i expecting:

- orange container with 5 item e.g when it has enough space and even more → [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iwqp3.png)
- orange container with 5 item e.g when space is not enough → [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vW7C.png)
- orange container with 2 item e.g when it has enough space and even more → [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJ5bz.png)
- orange container with 2 item e.g when space is not enough → [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n83yz.png)

thanks to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48395486/7872538 and little bit change to this math `margin: 0 calc(((75% / 25) - 12px) + 5%);`

i can handle 5 elements but when i delete one or more it looks like this → [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F50Ur.png)

with extra blank space.



here is my html:

```
<div class="red-container">
    <div class="orange-container">
       <div class="box-a size">A</div>
       <div class="box-b size">B</div>
       <div class="box-c size">C</div>
       <div class="box-d size">D</div>
       <div class="box-f size">F</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

here is my css so far:

```
.red-container {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px dotted red;
  float: right;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 100px 0;
}
.orange-container {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px dashed orange;
  float: right;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.size {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
}
.box-a {
  background: red;
}
.box-b {
  background: DodgerBlue
}
.box-c {
  background: green;
}
.box-d {
  background: orange;
}
.box-f {
  background: blueviolet;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Comment: It's very hard to help you without seeing any kind of code. Please include all relevant code, html css, jquery/javascript

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen thank you for respond. but no js/jquery yet i tried with css calc() but it did not turn out exactly what I wanted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `display:flex` so get the resided result.

I've added this, and changes your css a little.

```
.size {
  flex: 0 0 calc(15% - 10px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.size:last-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

This should be able to guide you to meet your requirements 100%

**Demo**

```css
.red-container {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px dotted red;
  float: right;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 100px 0;
}

.orange-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px dashed orange;
  float: right;
  margin: 10px 0;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.size {
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  //margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
}
.size {
  flex: 0 0 calc(10% - 10px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.size:last-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
}


.box-a {
  background: red;
}

.box-b {
  background: DodgerBlue
}

.box-c {
  background: green;
}

.box-d {
  background: orange;
}

.box-f {
  background: blueviolet;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="red-container">
  <div class="orange-container">
    <div class="box-a size">A</div>
    <div class="box-b size">B</div>
    <div class="box-c size">C</div>
    <div class="box-d size">D</div>
    <div class="box-f size">F</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great but items must have fixed with and height, because they are images and i don't want them to be stretched. instead, i want them to overlap, not stretch.
and they should look like the first and second photo that i uploaded.
and another thing that is missing is the margins between them (max 5px),
so this is a challenge for me if you could explain more to me. Thank you so much.
@CarstenLøvboAndersen